# Unable to upload media file toFirebase emulator

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-tools

Using Firebase tools `11.21.0` and `FIREBASE_STORAGE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:9199` and maven dependency

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
      <version>2.17.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I started the firebase emulator. And tried a simple file store:

```java
emulatorStorage = StorageOptions.newBuilder()
                    .setProjectId(projectId)
                    .setHost("http://localhost:9199")
                    .setCredentials(NoCredentials.getInstance())   
                    .build()
                    .getService();
```

And tried to save a file:

```
 byte[] compress = "test".getBytes();
           
            Blob blob = emulatorStorage.create(
                    BlobInfo.newBuilder(index, filename)
                            .setContentType("text/plain")
                            .build()
                    ,compress,
                    Storage.BlobTargetOption.doesNotExist());
```

but even with the content type set I get this every time:

```
com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: Failed to parse multipart request body part. Missing content type.
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException.translate(StorageException.java:163)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.translate(HttpStorageRpc.java:297)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.create(HttpStorageRpc.java:379)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.lambda$internalCreate$2(StorageImpl.java:208)
    at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:103)
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:76)
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:50)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.Retrying.run(Retrying.java:60)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.run(StorageImpl.java:1476)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.internalCreate(StorageImpl.java:205)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.create(StorageImpl.java:151)
```

and through debug I know that it is talking to the local emulator:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
POST http://localhost:9199/upload/storage/v1/b/demo-project.appspot.com/o?ifGenerationMatch=0&projection=full&uploadType=multipart
{
  "code" : 400,
  "message" : "Failed to parse multipart request body part. Missing content type."
}
```

What am I missing in the save operation, is the content type wrong? Or is this likely to be a bug in the emulator or compatibility issue with cloud-storage libs?

Comment: It's possible that this is a compatibility issue between the version of the Firebase emulator you are using and the version of the google-cloud-storage library you are using. I would suggest trying a different version of the google-cloud-storage library or using a different approach to uploading the file, such as using the put method of the Blob class instead.

Comment: tried with combinations of google-cloud-storage `2.15.0`,`2.16.0` and firebase-tools `v11.19.0` ,`v11.16.1` and get the same error message. I would be grateful for a snippet using the Blob class please.

Comment: Its possible its just not supported yet https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure#admin_sdk_availability

Answer (score 0):

<s>As mentioned by @Gridcell Coder, The Cloud Storage for Firebase emulator only supports a very small subset of the Cloud API and it is intended to only be used via the `firebase-admin` package. [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure#admin_sdk_availability) is not yet supported for Cloud Storage for Firebase.</s>

Comment: My own comment does point out limitations but I am trying a very basic operation here using the cloud storage library that is `insert` which according to this https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_storage#differences_from_google_cloud_storage should be supported.

Comment: @GridcellCoder, I have found [github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/5451) you raised and followed steps from there with both firebase v11.21.0 And v11.19.0 but I can successfully upload video files using `firebase emulators:start --project demo-project --debug`. Can you tell me why did you use `firebase-tools-linux` for which I'm getting `command not found error`. Is it by mistake?

Comment: Can you also tell me what is size of the video you are uploading?

Comment: I used `firebase-tools-linux` from here https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#mac-linux-standalone-binary and tried uploading a 4k image, a simple three letter String (as text file) and an image. May I ask are you using windows, mac or linux? As I am using the linux version.

Comment: As couldn't uncheck community wiki, I have added updated answer above. Can you have a look at it once?

Answer (score 0):

I have found [github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/5451) you raised and followed steps from there with both firebase v11.21.0 And v11.19.0 but I can successfully upload video files using `firebase emulators:start --project demo-project --debug`.

As per our conversation above in comments, it seems like you have mistaken `firebase-tools-linux` as a command. the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#mac-linux-standalone-binary) you followed to set up the forebase for linux will just have downloadable file name as  `firebase-tools-linux` It is just file name it does not mean that for linux we have to use `firebase-tools-linux` as a command for linux machines.If you observe step 3 in the doc you shared, It is pointing to [log in and test the CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#sign-in-test-cli) where we have to use `firebase login` only. Hence try with `firebase emulators:start --project demo-project --debug` command.

Steps I have taken

**Step 1:**
Cloned source code from the [github](https://github.com/gridcellcoder/firebase-emulator-debug) you shared. Changed directory to `firebase-emulator-debug`.

**Step 2:**
Ran below command

```
`firebase emulators:start --project demo-project --debug`.
```

**Step 3:**
Successfully uploaded video file of 2.3 MB from emulator.

FYI, I have also used the linux machine only for the above steps.

Comment: Please could you share your code or open a pull request on my repo to see if I can also upload the way you did. My example is for a text file not a video and it would be good to see your approach. The binary name should matter it's the same Firebase tool.

Comment: @GridcellCoder I have not changed anything from your [github code](https://github.com/gridcellcoder/firebase-emulator-debug). I just clonned your code and uploaded video file. You can look this [screenshot](https://i.paste.pics/L9VNG.png).

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with the latest versions at the time i.e., `fire-tools` version `12.9.1` and `com.google.cloud:libraries-bom` version `26.27.0`.

The following statement works when connecting with actual GCP storage but same `400 content type` error when connecting to Emulator:

```
storage.create(it, content.readAllBytes(), Storage.BlobTargetOption.doesNotExist())
```

However, this works with both emulator and actual GCP Storage:

```
storage.createFrom(it, content, Storage.BlobWriteOption.doesNotExist())
```

I didn't see the actual code as what is the main difference between these two methods, but it works.